# javascript using servlet data

Tags: javascript, servlets, request, el

I have a servlet that sets 5 parameters : balance1 , balance2, ...., balance5

in my .jsp file I am trying to get the data using ${balance#}. I am then going to push these values into an array, but for this purpose I am just using the `document.write(param)` for the example.

It ends up just spitting out the string without requesting the value.

```
for (var i = 0; i <5 ; i++) {
   var loan = "\"$" + "{balance" + i + "}\"";
   document.write("</br>");
   document.write(loan);
}
```

I tried both using with and without quotations around the call but it does not work unless I specifically write:

`document.write("${balance1}")`

what is the write way to retrieve data from a servlet into javascript.

Comment: You're going about this inside-out.  The servlet will generate code -- including Javascript code -- that will be interpreted by the browser.  By the time it makes it to Javascript, none of the server-side notions, including things like `${balance1}`, will have any meaning.  You will have to have already turned them into something that Javascript can use..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your balance parameters are of a number type, you can just do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var balanceArray = [
    ${balance1}, ${balance2}, ${balance3}, ${balance4}, ${balance5}
  ];
</script>
```

If it's text, you can just do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var balanceArray = [
    "<c:out value="${balance1}"/>"
  , "<c:out value="${balance2}"/>"
  , "<c:out value="${balance3}"/>"
  , "<c:out value="${balance4}"/>"
  , "<c:out value="${balance5}"/>"
  ];
</script>
```

I would suggest however to create a list of balance items, so you could solve it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var balanceArray = [
    <c:forEach items="${balanceList}" var="balance" varStatus="status">
      ${status.first ? '' : ', '}${balance}
    </c:forEach>
  ];
</script>
```